# Return a Boolean and an error message C#

Tags: c#, methods

I'm a quite new developer for C# and I have some problem in a creation of a DLL. I need to create a DLL that will be used by an external system to retrieve some information from my DB. Basically, they will send to me an ID and I need to send back the information related. This is my code:

```
public bool GetLotInfo (string SupplierCode, out stLotInfo LotInfo, out string ErrorMessage)
{
  //collect info
}
```

How can I return string ErrorMessage as the method is a Bool?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your method signature, just set it:

```
public bool GetLotInfo (string SupplierCode, out stLotInfo LotInfo, out string ErrorMessage)
    {
      //collect info
//Oops, error:
ErrorMessage = "Something bad happened";
    }
```

This works because ErrorMessage is declared as `out` parameter.

Comment: In new version of C# it's now possible to mark arguments as `nullable` by typing a question mark like this `out string? ErrorMessage`. And then initialize the value with null `ErrorMessage = null` in the beginning of the method.

Comment: @FrameMuse Great, not sure how that is relevant though.

Comment: This is just a comment... I thought

Answer (score 2):

Just *assign*:

```
public bool GetLotInfo (string SupplierCode, out stLotInfo LotInfo, out string ErrorMessage)
{
    //collect info

    // LotInfo is out parameter and must be assigned...
    LotInfo = new stLotInfo(...);

    // ... as well as ErrorMessage 
    ErrorMessage = "My Message";

    return true;     
}
```

....

```
stLotInfo myLotInfo;
string myMessage;

if (GetLotInfo("MyCode", out myLotInfo, out myMessage)) {
    //TODO: Put a relevant code with myLotInfo and myMessage 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`out` arguments are a special case of `ref` arguments; they are passed by reference and they *must* be set *before* the method returns. You can read more about them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx).

In your case, a sketch of a possible implementation would be:

```
public bool GetLotInfo(string supplierCode, out StLotInfo lotInfo, out string errorMessage)
{
    try
    {
        lotInfo = ... //whatever you need to do
        errorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
    catch (MyExpectedException e) //Put here the specific exceptions you are expecting,
                                  //Try to avoid catching the all encompassing System.Exception
    {
        errorMessage = e.Message;
        lotInfo = null;
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        //any clean up you need to do.
    }
}
```

Also, as additional advice, try to follow the c# naming guidelines:

1. Classes should be camel cased and the first letter should be upper case: `StLotInfo` instead of `stLotInfo`.
2. Arguments and parameters should be camel cased and the first letter should be lower case: `supplierCode` instead of `SupplierCode`, `errorMessage` instead of `ErrorMessage`, etc.
3. Try to avoid abbreviations unless commonly used and accepted: what is `St` in `StLontInfo`?

Answer (score 2):

In C# 7.0 you can also use tuples for that:

```
public (bool success, string message, LotInfo lotInfo) GetLotInfo(string SupplierCode)
{
    // collect info
    return (true, "message lot info retrieved successfully", new LotInfo()); // put actual values here
}
```

Method invocation:

```
var result = GetLotInfo("test");
WriteLine($"Success: {result.success}");
WriteLine($"Message: {result.message}");
WriteLine($"Lot: {result.lotInfo}");
```

See more info about tuples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)